# Rails Heroku Sidekiq Confirm Procfile is Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

I have set my Procfile in the root of my app:

```
web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 5 -v
```

and I can see that heroku sees it when I push my rails app up via `git push heroku master`

```
Procfile declares types      -> web, worker
```

The problem is that a bunch of jobs are just getting stuck in the "enqueue" section.

If I run `heroku run bundle exec sidekiq` from the command line, only then will the jobs process.

Any ideas on how I could debug this? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you started worker dynos? Heroku will only start the web process type automatically for you. Check the output of `heroku ps` - you'll probably only see your web process listed.

You would need to do;

```
 heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

to add a worker dyno and scale it to 1.