# Schedule background task with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron, sidekiq

I have a Rails 3 app deployed heroku. I have a Sidekiq worker at `app/workers/task_worker.rb`:

```
class TaskWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform
    ...
  end
end
```

How to schedule execution of `TaskWorker.perform_async` daily at 12:01 a.m?

Comment: Have you seen this video: http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq ? Can be helpful. Maybe these questions can help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188465/how-to-get-sidekiq-working-on-heroku http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687083/rails-heroku-sidekiq-confirm-procfile-is-working/16692308#16692308

Comment: @bodrovis, thanks but I didn't get the answer. I want to execute this task at specific time after every 24 hours.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to have a look at `sidetiq` too. https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq The gem supports complex timing expressions via the `ice_cube` gem.

I personally found comfortable to have a gem that would integrate seemlessly with sidekiq.

Something like that should work:

```
class TaskWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidetiq::Schedulable

  recurrence do
    daily.hour_of_day(0).minute_of_hour(1)
  end

  def perform
    # do magic
  end
end
```

Careful though when using this gem since there are some performance related issues with some time expressions. https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq/wiki/Known-Issues. The expression I gave you should circumvent this issue though.

Answer (score 4):

I don't like the overhead Sidetiq adds to Sidekiq so I sought out a different solution.

Apparently Heroku has a little-known, but free [scheduler addon](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) that allows you to run rake tasks every 10 minutes, hourly or daily. This is Heroku's answer to cron jobs and it's nice that it's a free add-on. It should work for most non-critical scheduling.

Heroku states in their docs that the scheduler is a "Best Effort" service which may occasionally (but rarely) miss a scheduled event. If it is *critical* that this job is run, you'll probably want to use a [custom clock process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler). Custom clock processes are more reliable but they count toward your dyno hours. (And as such, incur fees just like any other process.)

Currently it looks like [clockwork](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-ruby) is the recommended clock process on Heroku.

Answer (score -3):

I'm stating the obvious, but what's wrong with having a Cron Job that invokes the Sidekiq job every night at that time?

Comment: How can we configure that on heroku? Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: Look at the Schedule Cron gem for Ruby. You can configure your jobs there, and deploy.

Comment: 1. You need to involve your sysadmin; 2. You need to expose a service and secure it so it will be called only by localhost;

Comment: This is the beginning of an idea for an answer, it's not really a full solution.